# How to add Flake8 configuration file in pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, flake8

I would like to run pytest with Flake8 like this:

```
python3 -m pytest --flake8
```

I also would like to run Flake8 with following parameters:

```
max-line-length = 120
select = E,W,F,N,C
```

How can I do it? [Creating](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-flake8/) *setup.cfg* with this content did not change anything:

```
[pytest]
flake8-max-line-length = 120
flake8-select = E,W,F,N,C
```

Answer (score 2):

Editing **pytest.ini** (without setup.cfg or any other configuration file) helped my case:

```
[pytest]
flake8-select = E,W,F,N,C
flake8-max-line-length = 120
flake8-ignore = E201 E231
```

Without the **flake8-ignore** I didn't see any difference in output.

Answer (score -1):

The pytest section for `setup.cfg` is `[tool:pytest]` as of [version 4.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#pytest-4-1-0-2019-01-05) (fully removed in 4.1.0 as per pytest's removal process)

disclaimer: I'm a core dev of pytest

Comment: So it is
[flake8:pytest]
select = E,F,W,C
max-line-length = 120

or

[tool:pytest]
flake8-select = E,F,W,C
flake8-max-line-length = 120

Both options did not solve the issue. :-(

Comment: the latter -- what output do you expect and what output are you seeing?

Comment: I'd expect something like `python3 -m pytest --flake8 --flake8-select=E,F,W,C --flake8-max-line-length=120`. In other way: as if I run `flake8 --max-line-length=120 --select=E,W,F,N,C`.

Comment: please put both your output and expected in the question -- it's pretty helpful. it is working for me so you're not providing all the necessary info :) -- do you have other pytest configuration files? check `pytest.ini` / `setup.cfg` / `tox.ini` for other `[pytest]` / `[tool:pytest]` configs.

Comment: I have no idea what happened, but I've only updated pytest.ini (without setup.cfg) and added `flake8-ignore = E201 E231` line. After that pytest started using my other configuration (like flake8-max-line-length = 120).